# report postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, forms, report

There are ready-made forms in word / excel, you need to take data from postgres and substitute it. Analogs are jastreport / crystal report.
Is there something similar for postgres, or can I do it through rtf?
Thank!

Comment: Hello everyone! For some reason, some of the text was deleted!

Comment: Some of the tools you mentioned probably can connect to postgresql if you install the ODBC driver. https://odbc.postgresql.org/